# What does the last `点` mean in `玩得开心点`?

Tags: mandarin, adverbs

I've read the following phrases:

```
A: 妈妈，我可以和新邻居一起玩吗？
B: 可以，玩得开心点。
```

In the two sentences above, what does the `点` mean?

I think this is something like the following:

```
A: Mam, can I play together with those who moved recently?
B: Yes, you can. Have a good time.
```

Comment: Your translation is correct, 玩得开心点 means Have a good time/have fun. I think there is no proper way to translate 点 in this context, other than "Have 'some' fun", but that 'some' in the expression doesn't really sound natural in English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

点 or 一点 means *some* or *a bit*.

Just like we often use 很 (very) before adjectives and 些 (some) before nouns, we often need 点 just to make the sentence grammatical.

If you omit 点 saying 玩得开心, it sounds like a declarative sentence, rather than an imperative one.

Similarly, we say

```
快点 hurry up
小心点 be careful
慢点 take it easy
```

点 somehow functions like a sentence final particle like 吧, 了, etc. It is just used in certain types of sentences.